# Solving limits of trig functions.

Tags: limits

a) $$\lim_{x\to\pi/2^+} \frac{\ln(x-\pi/2)}{\tan(x)}$$
b) $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\ln(x)}{\arctan(x)}$$

How does one approach this question?

Comment: will this require L'hopitals rule?

Comment: The appropriate question is not "Will this require L'Hôpital's rule?" but rather "Ooh, am I so lucky that L'Hôpital's rule applies?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Second Question:**  As $x\to 0^+$, $\arctan x$ approaches $0$ through positive values. In the meantime, $\ln x$ becomes very large negative, so for positive $x$ near $0$, the ratio is very large negative.

Depending on the conventions you use, you can say that the limit is $-\infty$ or that it doesn't exist.

**First Question:** This was [asked and answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424850/limit-lim-limits-x-to-pi-2-frac-lnx-pi-2-tanx-using-de-lhop) a few hours ago.